# Multiple threads submit tasks and wait for results while another thread periodically executes each task

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have multiple threads that consume some data and call one third party service (`serviceA`). I can send only one request to `serviceA` per 10 second. Each thread have to wait until it receives a result from `serviceA` and then continue doing other thread specific work.

I want to implement some sort of proxy for `serviceA` that will receive all calls for `serviceA`, collect them, execute one call per 10 seconds and return a result of this call. Each thread should wait until the proxy returns the result. It should look something like this

```
public class ServiceAProxy implements ServiceA {

    private ServiceA serviceA;
    private ??? callsHolder;

    public ServiceAProxy(ServiceA serviceA) {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
    }

    public Result call(String parameter) {
        return callsHolder.submitAndWaitResult(() -> serviceA.call(parameter));
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void executeOldestCall() {
        callsHolder.executeOldestTask();
    }
}
```

Probably `callHolder` could be implemented using 2 [`SynchronousQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html)s but is there any cleaner solution to do this without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: If it is anyway blocking, you can probably try using [Guava RateLimiter](http://javadoc.scijava.org/Guava/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html).

Comment: @yegodm I will look into it, thanks.

Comment: It looks like JMS is more appropriate approach, rather than hold threads waiting to be served. With it you will have more flexibility to tune executions, throttle processes and do not get JVM/Memory overloaded with waiting threads.

Comment: @Vadim I have small fixed number of threads (about 5), so JMS would be overkill in my case.

Comment: But how about incoming requests load? 5 threads can produce a lot of data... BTW if it is not big I do not see any problems why do not use in-memory Queue with one of `Executor` implementatation (e.g. `org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool`)

Comment: @Vadim it's a possible solution but looks like Guava `RateLimiter` does exactly what I currently need. I will consider moving to JMS if it will not be able to handle requests load. Thanks.

Comment: @yegodm can you please post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case number of threads is small and  blocking of a calling thread until it can send the request is not a big deal, [Guava RateLimiter](http://javadoc.scijava.org/Guava/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) may be just enough. So your service proxy would look something like this:

```
public class ServiceAProxy implements ServiceA {
    private final ServiceA serviceA;
    private final RateLimiter throttle;

    public ServiceAProxy(ServiceA serviceA, double callsPerSecond) {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
        throttle = RateLimiter.create(callsPerSecond);
    }

    public Result call(String parameter) {
        // every thread may potentially block here until throttle allows it to proceed 
        throttle.acquire();
        return serviceA.call(parameter);
    }
}
```